# Binding Image to ListBox Item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть две коллекции с картинками

1. imageLeftList
2. imageBottomList

в XAML я привязуюсь к одной или к другой из колекций вот так:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding ElementName=imageLeftList, Path=SelectedItem.Path}" />
```

Как привязаться к двум колекциям сразу?

Comment: Ну либо делайте еще один контрол, который привяжется ко 2-й коллекции, либо делайте коллекцию, которая будет содержать в себе нужные элементы, объединив тем самым две коллекции.

Comment: Так и сделал практически, сделал событие SelectedChanged для одной и другой колекции.

Comment: почитайте про multibinding, там как раз привязка из нескольких источников